# Índice eficiente SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, índices

Srs.(as),

Preciso de uma ajuda para montar um índice eficiente para uma tabela no SQL.

Tenho uma tabela que está me causando uma certa dor de cabeça, pois é consultada com uma certa frequência, além de ter constantes inserts nela.

Meu sistema armazena arquivos de várias origens, criando uma estrutura em duas tabelas, sendo:

1-TB_ARQUIVO - Armazena o arquivo que foi criado
2-TB_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP - Armazena todo o conteúdo do arquivo (aqui está meu problema)
Essa tabela possui um `ID IDENTITY PK BIGINT` e uma coluna `ID_ARQUIVO BIGINT`, onde armazeno o ID da tabela TB_ARQUIVO. O conteúdo armazenado nessa tabela chega a 400 mil linhas por arquivo e atualmente temos cerca de 700 milhões de linhas.

Abaixo tem a estrutura da TB_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP e o índice que estou usando atualmente.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP](
    [ID] [bigint]  IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL,
    [ID_PRODUTO] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ID_ARQUIVO] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [COD_AGENCIA] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [COD_TOTAL] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,     
    [COD_REGIAO] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [VAL_VALOR] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [DES_DADOS_EXTRA] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [DAT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO] [datetime] NULL,
    [COD_SEGMENTO] [varchar](4) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TB_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP] ON [dbo].[TB_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP]
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [ID_ARQUIVO]
)
INCLUDE (
    [ID_PRODUTO],
    [COD_AGENCIA],
    [COD_SEGMENTO],
    [DAT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Complementando:
1 - O SQL Server que usamos é o Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise 2017.
2 - A coluna ID_ARQUIVO e DAT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO são as mais utilizadas para consultar dados na tabela

Comment: Se ID é a chave primária de TB_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP não entendi por qual motivo seu índice IDX_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP inclui tal campo em primeiro lugar já que apenas ele identifica univocamente cada linha de sua tabela. Será que um índice apenas em ID_ARQUIVO não seria melhor utilizado pelas sua aplicações?

Comment: Justamente, preciso de conhecimento mais apurado para me ajudar. Estou procurando a melhor forma de montar esse índice.

Comment: Pensa em algo assim?
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP] ON [dbo].[TB_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDO_VP]
(
 [ID_ARQUIVO]
)
INCLUDE (
 [ID_PRODUTO],
 [COD_AGENCIA],
 [COD_SEGMENTO],
 [DAT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO]) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]